# How does React router works and what is the difference between <link> and<Route>

Tags: reactjs, react-router

What is the difference between Link and Route in react router? 
Where do we use them or do we use them together or separately?
Where can I find genuine and professional React web development tutorial?

Answer (score 20):

The `Route` and `Link` components are meant to be used together to accomplish different tasks in the application. Firstly, the React Router library is intended to achieve two things: 1. Ensures that state transitions are captured in the URL bar. 2. Ensures that the application starts from a proper state when the visited through a stateful URL address.

**Role of Link Component**
The Link component is a way to transition route state in the application. So if you click a link component, a route state will be activated. For example:

```
<Link to="/example" />
```

will register that the application is in the '/example' state. At this point, it is up to the  component to render the appropriate content as such.

```
<Route path="/example" render={Profile] />
```

So in a nutshell, the Link component is responsible for the transition from state to state (page to page), while the Route component is responsible to act as a switch to display certain components based on route state.

The best example of the library usage can be found at https://reacttraining.com/react-router/

Comment: How you would go about dynamic routing? For example '/product/49' where you have to pass an ID and along with it a prop (type object).

Comment: Never mind, i'm watching the video on the link you supplied. Thanks for your excellent answer.

Comment: My pleasure to help

Answer (score 8):

## Link and Route

`<Link/>` is the element you could use to navigate through routes.

`<Route/>`, its most basic responsibility is to render some UI when a location matches the route’s path.

They are used separately. Link is dependent to Route's locations. But Route can be used without Link.

React Router: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/philosophy

React JS Tutorial: 
https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html

Comment: The way I understand Link is rendered link to the route, Route is its definition.

Answer (score 3):

In Layman's terms we could understand the difference as mentioned below:

a)Routes are responsible for rendering UI when its path matches current URL where as Links are similar to anchor tags  in HTML which are used to access the route paths.

b) Routes involve components within it where as  Links involve just the path which is already defined by the routes

c) Routes are independent entities where as Links are dependent on Routes.

Answer (score 2):

I will explain by an Example,
If I have:

```
<Router>
        <Route path = "/" component = {LoginModule} />
        <Route path = "/Register" component = {RegisterModule}/>
</Router>
```

Here if i go to URL `localhost:3000`, it will render the Login Module. No doubt in that.

But if I go to URL `localhost:3000/Register`, it will render both login and register module below the login module on the same page. It is because /Register also has '/' in it.

This can be solved by:

```
<Router>
        <Route exact = {true} path = "/" component = {LoginModule} />
        <Route path = "/Register" component = {RegisterModule}/>
</Router>
```

Comment: Answer is totally unrelated to questions asked. OP wants to know the way React Router works and the difference between <Routes/> and <Link/>

Answer (score 1):

A less tehcnical explanation:

1. **Route** helps to build routes. Creating a route one time is enough. For example:

```
    <Route exact path="/articles"> <Articles /> </Route>
```

means that "/articles" route is created and you do not have to create it again in other components. That's why generally Route goes inside the **main component**, which is generally "App".

2. Because of the first reason above, you will then need to use a linking tag in other components if you want to visit "/articles". If we use "**a**" tag, it will make the **browser** to send a fresh whole new html page. And this is what we do **not** want because we want only some parts (aka "component") of webpage to change, not all page.